# Android - Using Shared Preferences in separate class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to save data using Shared Preferences in android. But I am looking to use separate class to do this task. I have implemented that class like below,

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class SavePref {

    private Context context;

    public SavePref(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void saveInt(String key, int value) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.commit();

    }

}
```

But there is an error on `getActivity()`,

```
The method getActivity() is undefined for the type SavePref
```

How to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getActivity()` is a method of `Fragment` not of your `SavePref`. In your case the simple fix is to use the Context you are keeping as member variable to retrieve the `SharedPreferences`. An alternative to your approach is to avoid keeping the context as member variable, linking somehow the shared preferences to an instance of of your `SavePref` class, and have a static method

```
  public static void saveInt(Context context, String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

and address the method like:

```
SavePref.saveInt(getActivity(), key, value);
```

from a `Fragment` or

```
SavePref.saveInt(this, key, value);
```

from an `Activity`. This way you don't need to instantiate SavePref every time you need to call `saveInt`, and you can avoid to store a reference to the `Context`.

Answer (score 9):

I have created a class to do the same thing. This way you can save boolean, int, string data or check if data has been saved in a specific group of preferences for your app.

So, you need to create a class "DataProccessor.java" and put the content down bellow. Also I'm going to leave some examples about how to use it.

I hope it can helps you

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class DataProccessor {

    private static Context context;

    public DataProccessor(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public final static String PREFS_NAME = "appname_prefs";

    public boolean sharedPreferenceExist(String key)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        if(!prefs.contains(key)){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void setInt( String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static int getInt(String key) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        return prefs.getInt(key, 0);
    }

    public static void setStr(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String getStr(String key) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        return prefs.getString(key,"DNF");
    }

    public static void setBool(String key, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static boolean getBool(String key) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        return prefs.getBoolean(key,false);
    }
}
```

To use it I'll show you some small examples about how to save a String value in case you want to use it in an Activity, Fragment or Service.

**For an Activity**

```
 //// To Save a value
 DataProccessor dataProccessor = new DataProccessor(this);
 dataProccessor.setStr("email","johndoe@mail.com");

 //// To Retreive a value
 dataProccessor.getStr("email");
```

**For a Fragment**

```
 //// To Save a value
 DataProccessor dataProccessor = new DataProccessor(getActivity());
 dataProccessor.setStr("email","johndoe@mail.com");

 //// To Retreive a value
 dataProccessor.getStr("email");
```

**For a Service**

```
 //// To Save a value
 DataProccessor dataProccessor = new DataProccessor(getApplicationContext());
 dataProccessor.setStr("email","johndoe@mail.com");

 //// To Retreive a value
 dataProccessor.getStr("email");
```

Comment: Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)

Comment: @jeprubio I created it to be a separated class you can access anywhere, I know what you mean, but any user have to manage their memory usage the way they want

Answer (score 3):

change

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

You already have **context** then why should you used `getActivity()`?

Actually `getActivity()` is used to get context in `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple create the seprate  Constant Class in Your Project and call it very simple way when you need to save or retrive the data..

```
class Constant {

    companion object {

        val loginData: String = "LoginData"
        val token: String = "token"
        //create the fuction of shared prefrence
        fun setpref(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
            return context.getSharedPreferences("Table Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  class PreferenceUtil { 
    
     private var msharedPref: SharedPreferences? = null
     private var mEditor: Editor? = null
    
     companion object {
     private var sInstance: PreferenceUtils? = null
    
     fun getInstance(context: Context): PreferenceUtils {
                if (sInstance == null) {
                    sInstance = PreferenceUtils(context)
                }
                return sInstance as PreferenceUtils
            }
    }
    
     constructor()
    
        constructor(mContext: Context?) {
            msharedPref = mContext?.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE)
            mEditor = mSettings?.edit()
        }
        // get Boolean value
         fun getValue(key: String, defValue: Boolean): Boolean {
        return msharedPref!!.getBoolean(key, defValue)
    }
    // set Boolean value
    fun setValue(key: String, value: Boolean) {
        mEditor!!.putBoolean(key, value)
        mEditor!!.apply()
    }
 }


// Initialize the Pref class in your required class

class Abc : AppCompatActivity() {
   var mPreferenceUtil: PreferenceUtil = PreferenceUtils(this)

   mPreferenceUtil.setValue(ABC_POPUP, false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.app.luandryuser.Util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class DataStorage {



    public static final int INTEGER = 1;
    public static final int FLOAT = 2;
    public static final int LONG = 3;
    public static final int STRING = 4;
    public static final int BOOLEAN = 5;
    private Context ctx;
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor writer;

    public DataStorage(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences("rural", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        writer = pref.edit();
    }

    public void write(String key, int value) {
        writer.putInt(key, value);
        writer.commit();
    }

    public void write(String key, float value) {
        writer.putFloat(key, value);
        writer.commit();
    }

    public void write(String key, String value) {
        writer.putString(key, value);
        writer.commit();
    }

    public void write(String key, boolean value) {
        writer.putBoolean(key, value);
        writer.commit();
    }

    public void write(String key, long value) {
        writer.putLong(key, value);
        writer.commit();
    }

    public Object read(String key, int DataType) {
        Object response = new Object();
        if (DataType == INTEGER)
            response = pref.getInt(key, 0);
        else if (DataType == BOOLEAN)
            response = pref.getBoolean(key, false);
        else if (DataType == LONG)
            response = pref.getLong(key, 0);
        else if (DataType == STRING)
            response = pref.getString(key, "");
        else
            response = pref.getFloat(key, 0.0f);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can use this class :-

```
public class SharedPreferenceClass {
    private static final String USER_PREFS = "SeekingDaddie";
    private SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;

    // private String user_name = "user_name_prefs";
    // String user_id = "user_id_prefs";

    public SharedPreferenceClass(Context context) {
        this.appSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
    }

    //get value
    public int getValue_int(String intKeyValue) {
        return appSharedPrefs.getInt(intKeyValue, 0);
    }

    public String getValue_string(String stringKeyValue) {
        return appSharedPrefs.getString(stringKeyValue, "");
    }

    public Boolean getValue_boolean(String stringKeyValue) {
        return appSharedPrefs.getBoolean(stringKeyValue, false);
    }

    //setvalue

    public void setValue_int(String intKeyValue, int _intValue) {

        prefsEditor.putInt(intKeyValue, _intValue).commit();
    }

    public void setValue_string(String stringKeyValue, String _stringValue) {

        prefsEditor.putString(stringKeyValue, _stringValue).commit();

    }

    public void setValue_boolean(String stringKeyValue, Boolean _bool) {

        prefsEditor.putBoolean(stringKeyValue, _bool).commit();

    }

    public void setValue_int(String intKeyValue) {

        prefsEditor.putInt(intKeyValue, 0).commit();
    }

    public void clearData() {
        prefsEditor.clear().commit();

    }
}
```